# arrays indices in c programming

Tags: c, arrays, variables

Within c programming how can I swap elements of an array such that `x[1,2,3,4,...,i,i+1,...,n-1,n]` becomes `x[2,1,3,4,...i,i+1,...,n-1,n]` then `x[2,3,1,4,...,i,i+1,...,n-1,n]` then `x[2,3,4,1,...,i,i+1,...,n-1,n]` all the way to n and then back down to 1 again?

I so far have the following code where I have printed the un-shuffled array and then created a loop that should swap the elements around, however it only does this for the first two elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float temp;
float x[10];
int i,n;
double delta;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{/*main*/
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            delta=5;
            x[0]=5;
            x[i]=x[i-1]+delta;

            printf("X[%d] = %f\n", i, x[i]);
        }


    for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
        {

            temp=x[i];
            x[i]=x[(i+1)];
            x[(i+1)]=temp; 

            printf("\nResultant Array...\n");
            for (i=0;i<10;i++)
                {
                    printf("X[%d] = %f\n", i, x[i]);
                }

        }
}/*main*/
```

This prints;

```
X[0] = 5.000000
X[1] = 10.000000
X[2] = 15.000000
X[3] = 20.000000
X[4] = 25.000000
X[5] = 30.000000
X[6] = 35.000000
X[7] = 40.000000
X[8] = 45.000000
X[9] = 50.000000

Resultant Array...
X[0] = 10.000000
X[1] = 5.000000
X[2] = 15.000000
X[3] = 20.000000
X[4] = 25.000000
X[5] = 30.000000
X[6] = 35.000000
X[7] = 40.000000
X[8] = 45.000000
X[9] = 50.000000
```

If this had worked I was intending to write;

```
if(i+1==n)
{
temp=x[i+1];
x[i+1]=x[i];
x[i]=temp;
}
```

All within the for loop, in an attempt to cycle back down through the indices from n to 1.

I am new to programming and I really don't know where to go from here, so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having has to do with variable scoping! You're using the variable ***i*** in two loops where one is *nested inside* the other (I'm talking about the 2nd and 3rd FOR loops, as listed from top to bottom).

This means that both loops are incrementing the value of i (by executing separate i++ commands), so at the end of the first iteration of your 3rd FOR loop, the variable i has a value of 10, and therefore the program won't run the second iteration of the 2nd FOR loop.

I've changed the inner loop to work with a separate variable, called *j*. I also had to change some of the conditions of the FOR loops to make them work correctly (you were off by 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

float temp;
float x[10];
int i,j,n;
double delta;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{/*main*/
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            delta=5;
            x[0]=5;
            x[i]=x[i-1]+delta;

            printf("X[%d] = %f\n", i, x[i]);
        }


    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        {

            temp=x[i];
            x[i]=x[(i+1)];
            x[(i+1)]=temp; 

            printf("\nResultant Array...#%d\n",i);
            for (j=0;j<10;j++)
                {
                    printf("X[%d] = %f\n", j, x[j]);
                }

        }
}/*main*/
```

It gave these results:

```
X[0] = 5.000000
X[1] = 10.000000
X[2] = 15.000000
X[3] = 20.000000
X[4] = 25.000000
X[5] = 30.000000
X[6] = 35.000000
X[7] = 40.000000
X[8] = 45.000000
X[9] = 50.000000

Resultant Array...#0
X[0] = 10.000000
X[1] = 5.000000
X[2] = 15.000000
X[3] = 20.000000
X[4] = 25.000000
X[5] = 30.000000
X[6] = 35.000000
X[7] = 40.000000
X[8] = 45.000000
X[9] = 50.000000

Resultant Array...#1
X[0] = 10.000000
X[1] = 15.000000
X[2] = 5.000000
X[3] = 20.000000
X[4] = 25.000000
X[5] = 30.000000
X[6] = 35.000000
X[7] = 40.000000
X[8] = 45.000000
X[9] = 50.000000

Resultant Array...#2
X[0] = 10.000000
X[1] = 15.000000
X[2] = 20.000000
X[3] = 5.000000
X[4] = 25.000000
X[5] = 30.000000
X[6] = 35.000000
X[7] = 40.000000
X[8] = 45.000000
X[9] = 50.000000

Resultant Array...#3
X[0] = 10.000000
X[1] = 15.000000
X[2] = 20.000000
X[3] = 25.000000
X[4] = 5.000000
X[5] = 30.000000
X[6] = 35.000000
X[7] = 40.000000
X[8] = 45.000000
X[9] = 50.000000

Resultant Array...#4
X[0] = 10.000000
X[1] = 15.000000
X[2] = 20.000000
X[3] = 25.000000
X[4] = 30.000000
X[5] = 5.000000
X[6] = 35.000000
X[7] = 40.000000
X[8] = 45.000000
X[9] = 50.000000

Resultant Array...#5
X[0] = 10.000000
X[1] = 15.000000
X[2] = 20.000000
X[3] = 25.000000
X[4] = 30.000000
X[5] = 35.000000
X[6] = 5.000000
X[7] = 40.000000
X[8] = 45.000000
X[9] = 50.000000

Resultant Array...#6
X[0] = 10.000000
X[1] = 15.000000
X[2] = 20.000000
X[3] = 25.000000
X[4] = 30.000000
X[5] = 35.000000
X[6] = 40.000000
X[7] = 5.000000
X[8] = 45.000000
X[9] = 50.000000

Resultant Array...#7
X[0] = 10.000000
X[1] = 15.000000
X[2] = 20.000000
X[3] = 25.000000
X[4] = 30.000000
X[5] = 35.000000
X[6] = 40.000000
X[7] = 45.000000
X[8] = 5.000000
X[9] = 50.000000

Resultant Array...#8
X[0] = 10.000000
X[1] = 15.000000
X[2] = 20.000000
X[3] = 25.000000
X[4] = 30.000000
X[5] = 35.000000
X[6] = 40.000000
X[7] = 45.000000
X[8] = 50.000000
X[9] = 5.000000
```

I'll leave you to figure out how to go back down :)
Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

For looping from n to 0 use

```
 for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
```

Note that n-1 cause arrays start from 0

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is very useful :) !